# Extend Register Form

Tags: twig, registration, shopware6

Does anyone have any experience with extending the registration form in Shopware 6 with additional required fields?
I'm having a hard time getting this to work properly, since the registration form can be submitted even if all the required fields I added are empty.

What is the proper way to implement form violations my own?
I already made sure to add required="required" to the input.
I've seen it done two seperate ways in the twig templates regarding registration but none of them work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried if by myself, adding a form component with `required="required"` is enough for the frontend validation:

- added (for testing) at the top of `vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/views/storefront/component/address/address-personal-company.html.twig`

  ```
    <div class="form-now">
        {% block component_address_form_company_legal_label %}
            <label class="form-label"
                   for="{{ prefix }}legal">
                {{ "address.companyLegalLabel"|trans|sw_sanitize }}{% if accountTypeRequired %}{{ "general.required"|trans|sw_sanitize }}{% endif %}
            </label>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block component_address_form_company_legal_input %}
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control{% if violationPath %} is-invalid{% endif %}"
                   id="{{ prefix }}company"
                   placeholder="{{ "address.companyLegalPlaceholder"|trans|striptags }}"
                   name="{{ prefix }}[company]"
                   value="{{ address.get('legal') }}"
                   required="required">
        {% endblock %}

        {% block component_address_form_company_legal_input_error %}
            {% if violationPath %}
                {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/utilities/form-violation.html.twig' %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
  ```

The field is validated and I cannot submit the form (if I filled all but the custom field)

[image: Validation error]

- Make sure you have the _input_error_component
- In addition, you should always validate your data in the backend as well, so that nobody who can use the browsers dev-tools to delete required fields can override your validation.

  - Such a validation could be added by [decorating](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/adjusting-service) `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\RegisterRoute::register` and pass additional fields to the parameter `$additionalValidationDefinitions` and calling the original function.